# Black bar appearing in UIWebview when device orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that I am loading onto another view, everthing looks fine in portrait or landscape when rotating, however when I am in portrait and I zoom in slightly with pinch or double tap when I rotate from portrait to landscape the view dosnt fill completely with the uiwebview, there are about 10pxls on the right that turn black as outlined in this screen shot.

[image]

if you look carefully you can see the  outline of the scroll indicator in the black, which segests this is part of the uiwebview?? if so then why dose it turn black in this area.

Also heres another screen shot of the webview scrolled up abit so you can see its part of the uiwebview...

[image]

This is how I am adding the view onto the detail view.

```
- (void)viewdidload
//..

//Load in FirstView
    firstView = [[FirstMainViewController alloc] init];
    firstView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, firstView.view.bounds.size.width, firstView.view.bounds.size.height);

    firstView.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    firstView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.view insertSubview:firstView.view belowSubview:actionTabBar]; 

//..
```

Comment: UPDATE: This only ever happens when I double tap the img inside the uiwebview to zoom in.

Comment: Does this happen on iOS 5 as well?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try to set the background of the webView transparent (clearColor) and set it's opaque property to FALSE. Then make the background white in your html or simply have the view beneath the webView white.

Comment: LEDGEN!!!! can't belive how close I was to having this correct. Spent all yesterday working on it...  I just had to change the background color to clear and opaque to false and it worked perfectly! thank you very much...

Comment: Setting the webViews background color to clearColor has nothing to do with it. Setting the webViews opaque to NO will fix the issue, but can cause some extra overhead - slow.

Comment: You Should do it after Pdf/Html page Loaded in webview :-)

Comment: Setting Opaque NO takes away the black...and in my case it just became white (the background color) but the content in the web view was still "overlaid" by the white area. Setting the back color to clear does not help.

Comment: @DennisWelu Did you ever find a solution for that extra overlay?

Comment: @DennisWelu still does this in 2017 with iOS 10. Content in UIWebView is overlaid by background even if web view's background color is clear and opaque is NO. :-(

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and simply setting opaque to NO fixed it. Didn't even have to change the background color, it works fine with the background color set to white.

Comment: yea it may look hidden, but the extra space is still remain

Comment: @jeff9888 Did you ever find a solution for that extra space?

Answer (score 1):

I put in the line...

```
webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

webView is my @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled` and the black border goes away :
In `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add the following lines :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```