# WKWebView dynamic sizing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

In an app I am currently working on, `UIWebView` is used to display files such as PowerPoints and such. There is a drawer to the right of the web view that can be opened and closed via a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. As you resize, then open or close, a black artifact will appear on the right side of the web view, exactly as seen on this question: [Black bar appearing in UIWebview when device orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388534/black-bar-appearing-in-uiwebview-when-device-orientation-changes).

Between that issue, and the issue in iOS 8 with PDFs rendering with a black background, I decided to try out `WKWebView`. That doesn't have either issue, however when the web view's width changes dynamically (the right constraint is bound to the pan gesture) the content in the web view is very slow. The web view either doesn't resize, or is very choppy/blocky as it does. This issue isn't present when using `UIWebView`. Does anyone have either any pointers to fix the issue with `UIWebView` and that black artifact, or why `WKWebView` is performing so badly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: the `WKWebView`

My guess is that the webview is attempting to re-render its contents several times as the frame is adjusted. This could cause the choppiness, and there *may* not be much you can do about that. (not sure)

One way you could 'cheat' is by taking a snapshot of the webview before adjusting its frame, and laying it over top of the webview.

set the webview's `hidden` property to `YES` in hopes of killing the re-rendering as the frame is adjusted.

hook up the snapshot to the pan gesture recognizer, and when the gesture ends, give the webview its final frame and set `hidden` back to `NO`

at this point, you can remove the snapshot (maybe with an alpha animation) and the webview should only ever have to re-render its content once.

there will probably be a disparity between the snapshot's appearance and the webview's final appearance, but it should be workable.